# Typecasting generic object in NSUserDefault

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array stored in NSUserDefaults as an object.

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var details = [1,2,3]
defaults.setObject(details, forKey: "testing_array")

// this is wrong
var percentArray : Array? = defaults.objectForKey("testing_array") as Array
```

How do I retrieve and use it as an array? If I set it as anyObject, I cannot use it as an array later on.

Comment: Please read the Swift docs or at least search SO before posting. This is basic as Swift gets. Don't use the language until you've learned something about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result from objectForKey will be castable as an array of AnyObject, aka `[AnyObject]?`

You can't cast it as Array, since that's a generic and you can only cast to a specific class.

As Midhun points out, in this specific case, you actually have an array of Int, so you can use the more specific `[Int]?`

For even more safety use the `if let` construct to validate the casting:

```
if let percentArray = defaults.objectForKey("testing_array") as? [Int] {
    println(percentArray)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining! your as has a ?, while matt's "as" has no ? - what difference does that make?

Comment: Mine is conditional, it will return nil (and if let will fail) if the cast is not possible (because it's not an array of integers) where as Midhun's will thrown an exception and crash the application.  In my case, there's presumably some error handling code in an else clause.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
var percentArray : Array? = defaults.objectForKey("testing_array") as Array
```

Write:

```
var percentArray : Array<Int>? = defaults.objectForKey("testing_array") as? Array<Int>
```

Because when casting to array, you need to specify it's generic type also.

**EDIT:**

Based on matt's comment. You can also use:

```
var percentArray  = defaults.objectForKey("testing_array") as [Int]
```

Comment: Please don't show the `Array<Int>` syntax. Use the syntactic sugar `[Int]`. Also, please don't show unnecessary explicit declaration; `as?` types by inference.

Answer (score 1):

If you know for a fact that it is an array of Int, simply explain to Swift that it's an array of Int (by casting):

```
var percentArray = defaults.objectForKey("testing_array") as [Int]
```